# POST article with the open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with the open graph. I want to use the read action to publish an article.

I use this code :

```
FB.api(
'/me/news.reads',
'post',
{ article: document.location.href }
);
```

But, I have this error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) The Action Type news:Read is not approved, so app 145634995501895 can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app. User 100001447431244 is not one of those roles.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

With my account administrator, It's okay but not for all users.
In the documentation, I can see that the action read is a native action of Facebook and NOTE: Submissions for a custom Read action on a built-in Article object will no longer be accepted. But this action is not a custom Read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Submissions for a custom Read action on a built-in Article object will no longer be accepted. But this action is not a custom Read...

That does not mean that you will not have to submit the build-in action for review as well … and obviously you haven’t done this yet, and therefore you get the error message (which is btw. pretty self-explanatory, IMHO).

(Viewing a build-in action in your app’s OG settings clearly displays the *Approval Status* as well.)

Comment: Facebook tell me "Use a test account" but if I use a test account, Facebook return this message : 

/**/ FB._callbacks.__gcb6({"error":{"message":"Call to a member function on a non-object","type":"BadMethodCallException"}});

But the Facebook team don't want to approve my action.
What can I do ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved Pierre? I'm having the same problem.